# Create new tables from columns in main SQL table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, loops, sorting

I have a main SQL table, for example:

[image: Main Table]

I wish to create new tables from it.
It would split such that each column from the main table is a new SQL table (named "column"), and the columns in the new table are date (sorted earliest -> newest):

Table called "Weight" would be:

[image]

Table called "Salary" would be:

[image]

I am using python 3 and sqlite, and I am able to retrieve the (~200) column names of the main table into a dictionary or pandas dataframe using:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
tbl_info_command = "PRAGMA TABLE_INFO({table});".format(table=table)
df = pd.read_sql_query(tbl_info_command, conn)
attributes_wanted = ['name', 'type']
df_shrunk = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=attributes_wanted)
```

But unsure how to translate this into the above tables, or even whether a loop from a dict/ df is the most efficient approach. Or does sql have this functionality built in?

Comment: you can just pivot the tables, are you using pandas? you can do it within sql lite too quite easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). See the implementation below:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John', 'Allison', 'John', 'Allison'],
    'Date': ['20160101', '20160101', '20170605', '20170605'],
    'Weight': [80, 55, 84, 58],
    'Salary': [10000, 22000, 18000, 30000]
})
>>> df

    Name    Date    Weight  Salary
0   John    20160101    80  10000
1   Allison 20160101    55  22000
2   John    20170605    84  18000
3   Allison 20170605    58  30000

>>> df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Date', values='Weight')


Date    20160101    20170605
Name        
Allison 55          58
John    80          84

>>> df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Date', values='Salary')

Date    20160101    20170605
Name        
Allison 22000       30000
John    10000       18000
```

Comment: Excellent! Do I need to ensure date order (or is it automatic)? Is there a way to write the tables without loading into memory first? The main df is proving quite big.

Comment: The date order is alphabetical in the pivot table. There are a lot of ways how you can ensure low memory consumption for your df. I won't be able to answer unless I know your specific use case. If you're loading your df from CSV, you may want to look into `chunksize` parameter of [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method.